# Get back to a view with the same directions that existed before

Tags: ios, swift

well, guess this one is kinda big...

I'm making an app in which there will be a MapKit and a button. When the user clicks the button, he/she will open a new ViewController with several options of destinations to go. After confirming the one he wants to go, the MapKit view will reopen with directions for the specific place. To do this, I created a function on the ViewController linked to the MapKit view:

```
func createmap(latit: Double, longit: Double){

    //set what's going to show up in the Map
    MapView.delegate = self
    MapView.showsScale = true
    MapView.showsPointsOfInterest = true
    MapView.showsUserLocation = true

    //request authorization for user location data storage
    locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

    //if authorization is given, use the user location
    if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled(){

        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

    }

    //set source and destination coordinates of direction recommendation
    let sourceCoordinates = locationManager.location?.coordinate
    let destinationCoords = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latit, longitude: longit)

    //set placemarks with source and destination coordinates
    let sourcePlacemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: sourceCoordinates!)
    let destPlacemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: destinationCoords)

    //put placemarks on maps with the source and destination coordinates
    let sourceItem = MKMapItem(placemark: sourcePlacemark)
    let destItem = MKMapItem(placemark: destPlacemark)

    //set direction request, source and destination request coordinates and transport type
    let directionRequest = MKDirectionsRequest()
    directionRequest.source = sourceItem
    directionRequest.destination = destItem
    directionRequest.transportType = .automobile

    //set response if sucess or error
    let directions = MKDirections(request: directionRequest)
    directions.calculate(completionHandler: {

        response, error in
        guard let response = response else {
            if let error = error {
                print("Something went wrong.")
            }
            return
        }

        //set format of route line

        let route = response.routes[0]
        self.MapView.add(route.polyline, level: .aboveRoads)

        //set map framing
        let rekt = route.polyline.boundingMapRect
        self.MapView.setRegion(MKCoordinateRegionForMapRect(rekt), animated: true)


    })

}
```

And then, to make this function run, I did this:

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

        createmap(latit: lat, longit: long)

}
```

lat and long are variables declared publicly.

In the other view, I have a button called "go back to the Map" in which I try to make a simple segue. However, there is a problem with this code: if I get directions to some place, reopen the other view and then press "go back to the Map", the directions that were set disappear. I don't know what to do to make them stay, can someone please help?

just a bit more information: the "go back to the Map" button is linked to the MapKit view as a simple segue (i clicked, dragged and dropped to the MapKit view, didn't write any line of code)

Comment: put your code in viewWillAppear

Comment: @JaydeepVyas can you explain a little more? kinda new to the language

Comment: may be viewDidload is not called if your viewcontroller is already in NAvigationStack

Comment: to be honest, I don't think I understand what is NavigationStack... do you have any links to show me? trying to find some here too

Comment: are you facing any issue still now

Comment: @JaydeepVyas yes :( updated you on the post you made in this topic

Comment: your function is called when you back

Answer (score 1):

I think problem is your Map VC is already added into the navigation stack so ViewDidLoad method is not called again you should move your code from viewdidload to viewWill appear like

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(true)

        createmap(latit: lat, longit: long)

    }
```

Comment: sorry for the time I took to answer you again! i am still facing the same issue... nothing has changed i guess

Answer (score 0):

Did you used this Function to add a polyline? you added poly line correctly . but I think you had not provided values to poly line for drawing path

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
        let renderer = MKPolylineRenderer(overlay: overlay)
        renderer.strokeColor = UIColor.blue
        renderer.lineWidth = 4.0

        return renderer
    }
```

Comment: yes i did! sorry to not have added this to the main topic :)